# How to run multiple operations on Java 8 stream calls

Tags: java

Say I am converting `int []nums` to `List<Integer>` using java 8 streams as

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.stream(nums).mapToObj(i->i).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Also say, I want to see a standalone operation if all elements in `List<Integer>` have a value of say `5`, I can do this I think
`boolean match = list.stream().allMatch(s -> s.equals(list.get(5)));`

How can I combine the 2 where during `Arrays.stream()` not only do I convert it to `List<Integer>` but also track of all elements were same?

Comment: Do you need to be able to refer to the transformed list afterwards? If so, don't think there's any way to simultaneously do both.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to combine two totally different results in one go?

Answer (score 2):

You can't return more than one type from a stream.  So you would need to house the information in a class or some other structure (e.g. a map).  Here I create a class to hold the results. `SummaryStatistics` does something similar.

```
int[] nums = {5,5,5,5,5};
Info<Integer> results = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().reduce(new Info<>(),
        Info::add,
        (a,b)->a); // combiner - required but not used in this case

System.out.println(results.getList());
System.out.println(results.areAllTheSame());
```

prints

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
true
```

- The `add()` method both adds the value to the list and increments count if the `item` matches the `first` value added. `count` defaults to `1`. It also returns `this` to simplify the `reduce` method since the accumulator is expected to return the updated value.
- reduce first creates a class in which the values are stored.
- `allAreTheSame()` returns the `boolean` resulting from comparing the count to the list size.

```
class Info<T> {
    private T first = null;
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private int count = 1;

    public Info<T> add(T item) {
        list.add(item);
        if (first == null) {
            first = item;
        } else if (first == item) {
            count++;
        } 
        return this;
    }
    
    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public boolean areAllTheSame() {
        return count == list.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a teeeing collector to do both tasks simultaneously. Something like:

```
int[] nums = {6,5,5,5,5};
HashMap<String, Object> result = Arrays.stream(nums)
                                       .boxed()
                                       .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                                               Collectors.toList(),
                                               Collectors.filtering(i -> i != 5,Collectors.counting()),
                                               (myList, count) -> {
                                                   HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
                                                   map.put("myList", myList);
                                                   map.put("myBool", count == 0);
                                                   return map;})
                                               );

System.out.println(result.get("myList"));
System.out.println(result.get("myBool"));
```

**But just because you can doesn’t mean you should**

It is much more understandable and cleaner not to combine two operations that give two completely different results, but to do them separately. There is nothing wrong with:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().toList();
boolean allFives = list.stream().allMatch(i -> i == 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How can I combine the 2 where during `Arrays.stream()` not only do I convert it to `List<Integer>` but also track of all elements were same?"*

I guess you could assign *null* to *l* if *nums* is not all *5*'s.

```java
int []nums = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> l
    = IntStream.of(nums).allMatch(i->i == 5)
    ? IntStream.of(nums).boxed().toList()
    : null;
```